# aws cdk not creating s3 trigger for lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-cdk

I am trying to create a s3 trigger on a lambda using python cdk . I created lambda using cdk but it's working fine and other then that many other resources aswell created using cdk but on lambda it's not creating trigger my code is this :

```py
import aws_cdk.aws_lambda_event_sources as eventsources
import aws_cdk.aws_s3 as s3


    my_lambda.add_event_source(
        eventsources.S3EventSource(
            mybucket,
            events=[s3.EventType.OBJECT_CREATED], 
            filters=[
                s3.NotificationKeyFilter(
                    prefix="start", 
                    suffix="mysufix.csv",
                ),
            ],
        )
    )
```

Comment: Is there an error message?

Comment: @MarkSailes no everything is working fine :(

Comment: Check the S3 bucket, if there are other notifications for Lambda functions which no longer exist I don't think it'll create new ones.

Comment: @MarkSailes I checked notification of s3  . there are other notifications related to my other lambda .

Comment: @MarkSailes I just noticed cdk not even detecting change . even I tried with other prefix . cdk saying no change detected

Comment: Be careful about using the S3 Notifications like this. If you have multiple lambdas trying to listen to the same bucket you can run into cases where one lambda removes the triggers for the other lambdas. I've seen this a few times. Consider moving to using EventBridge rules instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create an instance of `eventsources` as `S3EventSource` is a class and addEventSource method needs `IEventSource` as source param

```
import aws_cdk.aws_lambda_event_sources as eventsources
import aws_cdk.aws_s3 as s3


my_lambda.add_event_source(
    new eventsources.S3EventSource(
        mybucket,
        events=[s3.EventType.OBJECT_CREATED], 
        filters=[
            s3.NotificationKeyFilter(
                prefix="start", 
                suffix="mysufix.csv",
            ),
        ],
    )
)
```

Docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_lambda_event_sources.S3EventSource.html